# Find the absolute extrema of the function $f(x,y)=x^2 + xy + y^2$ on the closed disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

> Find the absolute extrema of the function $f(x,y)=x^2 + xy + y^2$ on
>   the closed disk $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

I found $f_x = 2x + y $

$f_y= 2y+x$

Equated them to zero and Solving them gives $x=0 \; \; y=0$

But I am having difficulty finding critical points on the boundary

If I solve for $x \; or \; y$ in the disk equation, I will get $\pm$ values

How can I get the critical points on the boundary ?

Comment: Parameterize it: $x = \cos(t)$, $y=\sin(t)$, $g(t) := f(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ then it's a single variable calculus problem :)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}((x+y)^2+x^2+y^2)\le \dfrac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2+2(x^2+y^2))\le \dfrac{3}{2}$$

The extrema occurs at $(x,y)=(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's multipliers,

$$h(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2+\lambda (x^2+y^2)$$

$$h_x=0\implies2x+y+\lambda(2x)=0$$

$$h_y=0\implies2y+x+\lambda(2y)=0$$

Now, write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\lambda$ and substitute in $x^2+y^2=1$ to get $\lambda$ and then the values of $(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer in this post : [$\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha<2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295910/sin-alpha-cos-alpha2/2295971#2295971)

On the boundary, let's consider $(x,y)$ in the first quadrant: $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+xy=1+xy=1+\mathcal A$$

Where $\mathcal A$ is the area of the rectangle determined by $x=\cos(\theta)$ and $y=\sin(\theta)$.

The area of a rectangle with fixed diagonal (here $1$ the radius of the circle) is maximum for a square.

So $f(x,y)=1+\mathcal A$ is maximum when $x=y=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}$ or $\theta=\frac{\pi}4$.

The other solution is $(-x,-y)$ by symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

Use symmetry of the objective function and the form of the constraint to notice that the maximum occurs where the line $x=y$ intersects the unit circle.  Then the maximized value is $3/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Use polar coordinates. $$x^2+xy+y^2=r^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta)=r^2\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)\right)$$
With $\theta$ varying from $0$ to $2\pi$, the maximum of the expression in parentheses is $3/2$ at $2\theta=\pi/2$, and the minimum is $1/2$. Since $r^2$ varies between $0$ and $1$, your function has a minimum of $0$ at $(0,0)$, and a maximum of $3/2$ at $x=y=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Also won't $ x=\cos \theta$ and  $y = \sin \theta$ be a better substitution because we are given $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: It's a disk, so you can imagine it's made out of circles with radius $r$, with $0\le r\le 1$. You are given $x^2+y^2\le 1$ not $x^2+y^2=1$. This also gives you the range in angles, from $0$ to $2\pi$ (or any interval with length $2\pi$)

Comment: But absolute extremum can occur only on the boundary so $r=1$ right ?

Comment: If I take $r$ as variable then again it becomes a two variable problem

Comment: You don't know at the beginning that the extremum is at the boundary. How about if the function is something like $e^{-x^2-y^2}$?